# Buy and selling Bitcoin in different currencies

Tags: trading, currencies

If I were to purchase one Bitcoin in Australian (AUD) that is in the tens of thousands of dollars as of this moment, would I be able to sell this bitcoin in American (USD), which is in the thousands? Subsequently making profit from the process as the US dollar is worth more than the Australian.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the price in each currency would have the exchange rate factored into it, you would most likely make a loss due to exchange fees converting from AUD to USD and back after you buy/sell. (assuming the price of bitcoin was stable through the whole process)